# Merging data from rows based on conditions or sequences

Tags: r, merge, conditional-statements, sequence

I have the following data:

```
Data <- data.frame(Project=c(123,123,123,123,123,123,124,124,124,124,124,125,125,125,126,126),
                     Value=c(1,4,7,3,8,9,8,3,2,5,6,2,2,1,8,3),
                     OldValue=c("","Open","In Progress","Complete","Open","In Progress","Complete","Open","In Progress","System Declined","In Progress","","Open","In Progress","In Progress",""),
                     NewValue=c("Open","In Progress","Complete","Open","In Progress","Complete","Open","In Progress","System Declined","In Progress","Complete","Open","In Progress","Complete","","In Progress"))

Data$First <- ifelse(((Data$OldValue==""|Data$OldValue=="Complete"|Data$OldValue=="System Declined")&Data$NewValue=="Open"),Data$Value,NA)
Data$Second <- ifelse(((Data$OldValue=="Open"|Data$OldValue=="Complete"|Data$OldValue=="System Declined")&Data$NewValue=="In Progress"),Data$Value,NA)
Data$Third <- ifelse(((Data$NewValue=="Complete"|Data$NewValue=="System Declined")&Data$OldValue=="In Progress"),Data$Value,NA)
```

[image]

For each unique Project ID, I want to combine the First, Second & Third values into one row. I only want to do this if the values in the NewValue column follow either of the sequences below:

Open, In Progress, Complete
or
Open, In Progress, System Declined

So Project 123 would have two rows of data, and Projects 124 & 125 would have one. Rows 10 and 11 would be excluded as it didn't meet the above sequence

What's the easiest way to code for this?

Answer (score 0):

a solution using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>% group_by(Project) %>%
    mutate(
        fl = as.numeric(NewValue),
        flag = paste(lag(fl, 2, default = 0),
                     lag(fl, 1, default = 0),
                     fl, sep = ''),
        merge = paste(lag(Value, 2, default = 0),
                      lag(Value, 1, default = 0),
                      Value, sep = ',')
    ) %>%
    filter(flag == '321' | flag == '324') %>%
    select(Project, merge)

#   Project merge
#     <dbl> <chr>
# 1     123 1,4,7
# 2     123 3,8,9
# 3     124 8,3,2
# 4     125 2,2,1
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be one way to achieve your goal. I wanted to create a sequence of numbers which can represent the two patterns that you specified (i.e., Open-In Progress-Complete, and Open-In Progress-System Declined). For this reason, I collapsed factor levels into three using `fct_collapse()`. Then, I converted the new factor levels into numeric. Then, I wanted to create subgroup within each `Project`, which I have done in the second `mutate()`. The next task was to change the order of elements in `First`, `Second`, and `Third`. You wanted to have numbers in one row. So I used `sort()`. There was one condition to apply this operation, which is `identical(check[1:3], as.numeric(1:3))`. If you have either of the two patterns, you should expect a sequence of 1, 2, 3 in `check`. You use this logical check for each group. As long as this logical condition is met, `sort()` is applied to the three columns in each group defined by `Project` and `group`. Finally, I removed `check` and `group`, which I used for this whole operation.

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

Data %>%
mutate(check = as.numeric(
                   as.character(fct_collapse(NewValue, 
                                             `1` = "Open",
                                             `2` = "In Progress",
                                             `3` = c("Complete", "System Declined"))))) %>%
group_by(Project) %>%
mutate(group = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(check) != 1))) %>%
group_by(Project, group) %>%
mutate_at(vars(First:Third),
          funs(if(identical(check[1:3], as.numeric(1:3))){
               sort(., na.last = TRUE)} else{.}
          )) %>%
select(-check, -group)

#   group Project Value        OldValue        NewValue First Second Third
#   <int>   <dbl> <dbl>          <fctr>          <fctr> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1      1     123     1                            Open     1      4     7
#2      1     123     4            Open     In Progress    NA     NA    NA
#3      1     123     7     In Progress        Complete    NA     NA    NA
#4      2     123     3        Complete            Open     3      8     9
#5      2     123     8            Open     In Progress    NA     NA    NA
#6      2     123     9     In Progress        Complete    NA     NA    NA
#7      1     124     8        Complete            Open     8      3     2
#8      1     124     3            Open     In Progress    NA     NA    NA
#9      1     124     2     In Progress System Declined    NA     NA    NA
#10     2     124     5 System Declined     In Progress    NA      5    NA
#11     2     124     6     In Progress        Complete    NA     NA     6
#12     1     125     2                            Open     2      2     1
#13     1     125     2            Open     In Progress    NA     NA    NA
#14     1     125     1     In Progress        Complete    NA     NA    NA
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I ran into an issue when applying this to mt larger data set. I realized that there are a couple of instances where the OldValue, NewValue relationship isn't covered in my original logic (Data$First, Data$Second, Data$Third). I updated the original code in the question to reflect the exact instance that I'm talking about. When I rerun the code with the new data, I get the error "R Session Aborted. R encountered fatal error. The session was terminated".

Comment: @Dfeld What is your data size? I will have a look of your question later since I gotta get ready for my work now. Hope you do not mind.

Comment: There are about 10,000 lines imported from a csv file. I've tested it on a couple thousand lines successfully, but instances like the one I explained above and added to the code are causing R to crash. Thanks again jazzurro. No rush

Comment: @Dfeld I used your new data and ran my code above. I did not see any error messages. R did not crash either. The code successfully created Das for `Project 126`. You have 10,000 rows. I think that is a relatively large number, but I do not think that is a particularly large number. Since I do not have your data, I do not know what is causing the issue. One thing I can suggest is to divide the data into a few pieces. Since you manage to make the code work for a few thousands rows, this could be an easy workaround.

Comment: Not sure what happened, but I restarted R and it worked. Thanks again for the help

Comment: @Dfeld I am glad to hear that. If you are content with the idea above, please click the green tick under the triangles for up/down voting. That's SO's convention.